# Property can retain an autoreleased object?

Tags: objective-c

If I do this:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeObject* someInstance;`

Why isn't `someInstance` still around even when I use an autorelease initializer on it?

For example:

`someInstance=[SomeObject autoreleaseMethod];`

I would expect `someInstance` to retain it in this case so you can use `someInstance` later, but is this not true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property will only retain the object if you are using it's setter. In your example you forgot the `self.`:

```
self.someInstance = [SomeObject autoreleasedObject];
```

Comment: ah! of course. thank you. if i use an `alloc` method, i'd have to release twice if I use the `self.property` right?

Comment: Once when you're done using it, in the scope you created it. Once when (in this example) self is done using it, usually in it's dealloc method..